# SQL Server Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to add data to a table in SQL Server, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. However, it gives me this error:

> SQLException was undandled by user code.
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Here's my codes:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open(); // establish a database connection
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText =
        "INSERT INTO Products VALUES (@CatID, @Name, " +
        "@Image, @Description, @Price)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CatID", SqlDbType.Int).Value =
        ddlCategories.SelectedItem.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
        txtName.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
        "http://localhost:12345/CAPSTONE/images/" + fuImage.FileName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value =
        txtDescription.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value =
        txtPrice.Text;
    // saving the image file to your website folder 'Images'
    fuImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/" + fuImage.FileName));
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

Comment: What is a structure of `Products` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-check the primary key (I assume if your product ID) of your Products table if it's value is set to auto increment (Identity Specification > Is Identity = true)

Answer (score 4):

you must make all column of your database table in your query when you use this methode (and do not enter a value for Id if it's auto increment)
in you case

```
 "INSERT INTO Products VALUES (@CatID, @Name, " +
    "@Image, @Description, @Price)";
```

you have only 5 column and CatID is not an auto increment value ! you have to check that if true !

and you can choose the values do you want to make by this query

```
  cmd.CommandText ="INSERT INTO Products (CatID, Name,Image, Description, Price) 
                    VALUES  (@CatID, @Name,@Image, @Description, @Price)";
```

Comment: Just some additional information. I've seen this problem too. But the odd thing that I noticed, is that the statement works perfectly fine in one database, but throws that error in an exact copy of the same database. I'm curious as to why that might be, so as to gain a better understanding of what is happening behind the curtain.

Answer (score 0):

This means that your `Products` table has more or less columns than those you've supplied in your `VALUES` statement.

```
(@CatID, @Name, @Image, @Description, @Price)
```

If you perform the query `sp_columns Products` in management studio, it will list all of the columns in the table.

If however, you only want to insert those values, you would need to perform the following query instead:

```
INSERT Products (CatID, Name, Image, Description, Price)
```

When you specify an `INSERT` statement without specifying the column names, it expects all columns to be populated

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch block , and figure out the exact problem in catch, it will say what you missing, rest most of the possible answers have been given above

Answer (score -4):

```
    private void btninsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Empinfo values ('" + textBox1.Text + "''" + textBox2.Text + "''" + textBox3.Text + "''" + textBox4.Text + "')", con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Insert the record");
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("e1");
            }
            finally
        {

        con.Close();

    }
    }
```