# C# Why do i keep getting an error exception in inserting a data in a database?

Tags: c#

I created a table named as BUDGET_FINALTEST, and it just keeps on having an exception error whenever i run it in my button?

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into BUDGET_FINALTEST values (@EMPLOYEE_ID,@LAST_NAME,@FIRST_NAME,@DIVISION,@DATE_OF_BUDGET,@BUDGET)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMPLOYEE_ID", tbEmployeeID.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LAST_NAME", tbLName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIRST_NAME", tbFName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIVISION", tbDivision.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_OF_BUDGET", dateTimePicker2.Value.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BUDGET", tbBudget.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occured in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Column name or number of supplied values does
>   not match table definition

Comment: If you don't give the error, it won't be possible for us to help. Have a look at How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403243/sql-server-insert-error-column-name-or-number-of-supplied-values-does-not-match)

Comment: @EdwardGarcia in the future to help you in regards to not spinning your wheels, the error message could have been googled first of all, secondly, you should and could have googled basic insert command syntax

Answer (score 5):

You have the wrong number of parameters, or they are on the wrong order.
Always specify the columns list in your insert statement.
That will prevent you from making mistakes like this, as well as keep your code valid even if new columns are added to the table.

```
"insert into BUDGET_FINALTEST values (@EMPLOYEE_ID,@LAST_NAME,@FIRST_NAME,@DIVISION,@DATE_OF_BUDGET,@BUDGET)"
```

Should be

```
"insert into BUDGET_FINALTEST (EMPLOYEE_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, DIVISION, DATE_OF_BUDGET, BUDGET) values (@EMPLOYEE_ID,@LAST_NAME,@FIRST_NAME,@DIVISION,@DATE_OF_BUDGET,@BUDGET)"
```

Comment: additional note: this issue is *particularly common* when the fist column is a PKID that the user doesn't want to (and can't) supply the value for, or when there's a row-version tracking column - basically: anything that the database is going to provide the values for automatically

Comment: @MarcGravell very true indeed. thanks for reminding that!